# iPad UIView to PDF - low resolution

Tags: ipad, pdf, resolution

I have an app in which PDF is shown in UIWebView, and on top of that I put some UITextFields that need to be filled. The problem is when I generate new PDF from these views, PDF (from UIWebView) resolution stays ok, but text from UITextFields are fuzzy. How to fix that?

I have the following code to generate PDF:

```
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to upscale your View. Have a look at this, he gives a nice explanation:

http://cadabracorp.com/blog/2012/09/26/creating-printing-and-emailing-high-resolution-pdfs-in-ios/